# Outer join not working in my app

Tags: php, codeigniter

Outer join in codeigniter not working

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('userdetails','users.user_id=userdetails.user_id','outer');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->result())
       return $query->result();
    else
        return false;
```

Please help

Comment: The method is fine, your table structure probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply, am getting matching records only using this method.Any alternatives for this

Comment: Try `right`. Check if you get the expected data. And if possible post your **Table Structure**

Comment: the error am facing is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN `userdetails` ON `users`.`user_id`=`userdetails`.`user_id`' at line 3

Comment: Try `userdetails.user_id=users.user_id`

Comment: i have tried this, same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111044/discussion-between-hendra-nucleo-and-youv).

Comment: Then your table structure not support for outer. Try `INNER` instead

Comment: @HendraNucleo Syntax errors don't depend on table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write an outer join in MySQL, the keyword `LEFT` or `RIGHT` is required, while `OUTER` is optional. So use:

```
$this->db->join('userdetails','users.user_id=userdetails.user_id','left');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.